# When was MyBitcoin created?

Tags: e-wallet, history

MyBitcoin used to be an online Bitcoin shared eWallet. It was the go-to place for easily handling bitcoins. The site eventually shut down with a major loss of coins, widely suspected to be perpetrated by the service operator.

Its time of closing down is well known (July 2011) but I could not find a reference for when it was opened.

(Potentially relevant reading: [What is the story behind MyBitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/what-is-the-story-behind-mybitcoin), [How much Bitcoin was lost in the Jul. 2011 MyBitcoin site shutdown incident?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/how-much-bitcoin-was-lost-in-the-jul-2011-mybitcoin-site-shutdown-incident))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mybitcoin.com` domain existed no earlier than 2010-04-25, according to the domain name registration record (whois).

According to [the `mybitcoin.com` history at archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20110315000000%2a/http://www.mybitcoin.com), the domain first appears to have useful content sometime in early February 2011.

In case the above archive.org url doesn't work (seems to have a problem for me), copy and paste it from here:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20110315000000*/http://www.mybitcoin.com
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted since it's good to know, puts a lower bound and an anchor on the date. But not accepted since it doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: The above problem with a clickable archive.org URL has been reported on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220324/problem-with-clickable-archive-org-urls).

Comment: Feb 2011, interesting. Much later than I thought, only a few weeks before I knew Bitcoin.